# how to sort entries similar to a linked list?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, linked-list

I have the following data structure and i'd like to sort this based on the `before` and `after` values.

```
array (size=5)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 14
      'parentId' => int 0
      'before' => int 15
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 15
      'parentId' => int 0
      'after' => int 14
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 9
      'parentId' => int 0
      'after' => int 15
  3 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 8
      'parentId' => int 0
      'after' => int 9
  4 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 1
      'parentId' => int 0
      'after' => int 14
```

Is there neat way to do this with PHP?

Comment: function usort() - http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Comment: @splash58 Precisely no! http://stackoverflow.com/q/38008964/476

Comment: Can you more precisely describe how you would like it sorted? Is it something with: 'after : 9' means after all entries with ID lower then 9, and 'before : 10' means that all values higher then 10 should come after this one?

Comment: @rbaker86 write order of ids that should be in result

Comment: Thanks. I'd expect The keys to be in the order 0, 4, 1, 2, 3. I realise both 1 and 4 specify "after: 14", which takes precedence is not important for this scenario.

Comment: @deceze this is Unclear, right?  Do you understand the expected sorting rules?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a straightforward "one-liner" type solution to this.

I'm not clear whether `parentId` has any significance on the sorting, but if not this feels quite similar to [this question about sorting an array of Javascript includes by dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37927863/sort-array-dependent-of-another-array-keys-values) I answered earlier this week.

The only real difference is that before you can sort by dependency you'll need to convert those "before" entries into "after" entries on the corresponding row.

```
$data = [
    ["id" => 14, "parentId" => 0, "before" => 15],
    ["id" => 15, "parentId" => 0, "after" => 14],
    ["id" => 9,  "parentId" => 0, "after" => 15],
    ["id" => 8,  "parentId" => 0, "after" => 9],
    ["id" => 1,  "parentId" => 0, "after" => 14]
];

// Use the ID of each element as the array index.
$data = array_combine(array_column($data, "id"), $data);
// Convert each "after" entry into an array.
$data = array_map(function($element) {
        $element["after"] = isset($element["after"]) ? [$element["after"]] : [];
        return $element;
    }, $data);
// Convert each "before" entry into an "after" entry.
foreach ($data as $id => $element) {
    if (isset($element["before"])) {
        $data[$element["before"]]["after"][] = $id;
        unset($data[$id]["before"]);
    }
}
// Remove empty "after" entries.
$data = array_map(function($element) {
        if (!count($element["after"])) {
            unset($element["after"]);
        }
        return $element;
    }, $data);

$sorted = [];
while ($count = count($data)) {
    // Remove any met dependencies.
    foreach ($data as $id => $element) {
        if (isset($element["after"])) {
            foreach ($element["after"] as $after_id => $after_element) {
                if (isset($sorted[$after_element])) {
                    unset($data[$id]["after"][$after_id]);
                }
            }
            if (!count($data[$id]["after"])) {
                unset($data[$id]["after"]);
            }
        }
    }
    // Add elements with no more dependencies to the output array.
    foreach ($data as $id => $element) {
        if (!isset($element["after"])) {
            $sorted[$id] = $element;
            unset($data[$id]);
        }
    }
    if (count($data) == $count) {
        die("Unresolvable dependency");
    }
}
var_dump($sorted);
/*
array (size=5)
  14 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => int 14
      'parentId' => int 0
  15 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => int 15
      'parentId' => int 0
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => int 1
      'parentId' => int 0
  9 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => int 9
      'parentId' => int 0
  8 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => int 8
      'parentId' => int 0
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the `uasort()` function for your needs.
To define your comparison function, I would suggest to transform all the `after` conditions to the `before`conditions:

```
$array = [
    [
        'id'       => 14,
        'parentId' => 0,
        'before'   => 15
    ],
    [
        'id'       => 15,
        'parentId' => 0,
        'after'    => 14
    ],
    [
        'id'       => 9,
        'parentId' => 0,
        'after'    => 15
    ],
    [
        'id'       => 8,
        'parentId' => 0,
        'after'    => 9
    ],

    [
        'id'       => 1,
        'parentId' => 0,
        'after'    => 14
    ]
];

//transform all after conditions to before conditions
function defineBeforeCondition($array)
{
    $befores = array_column($array, 'before', 'id');
    $afters  = array_column($array, 'after', 'id');
    return array_merge(array_chunk($befores, 1, true), array_map('array_flip', array_chunk($afters, 1, true)));
}

$condition = defineBeforeCondition($array);
```

Now you could use the `$condition` in your comparison function:

```
$compare = function ($array1, $array2) use ($condition)
{
    //iterate through before conditions
    foreach ($condition as $before) {
        //if there is a match
        if (isset($before[$array1['id']]) && $before[$array1['id']] === $array2['id']) {
            //if the value of the first element is greater than the value of the second element,
            //but the first element should precede the second, return -1
            if ($array1['id'] > $array2['id']) {
                return -1;
            }
            //otherwise make a normal comparison
            //note the spaceship operator for PHP >= 7.0
            return $array1['id'] <=> $array2['id'];
        }
    }
    //no data, move down the first element
    return 1;
};

uasort($array, $compare);
var_dump($array);

array (size=5)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 14
      'parentId' => int 0
      'before' => int 15
  4 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 1
      'parentId' => int 0
      'after' => int 14
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 15
      'parentId' => int 0
      'after' => int 14
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 9
      'parentId' => int 0
      'after' => int 15
  3 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 8
      'parentId' => int 0
      'after' => int 9
```